# ValueError: input tensor must have rank 5 at least (depthwise_conv2d)

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution

I am trying to get [this repo](https://github.com/POSTECH-IMLAB/LaneSegmentationNetwork) running.

I found this [github issue](https://github.com/POSTECH-IMLAB/LaneSegmentationNetwork/issues/8) which is not resolved yet and also points at my problem.
I am using Tensorflow 1.13.1 (also tried with 1.14) and python 3

The error I am getting is in depthwise_conv2d:

```
 "input tensor must have rank %d at least" % (expected_input_rank))
 ValueError: input tensor must have rank 5 at least
```

When checking my tensors I get the following:

```
input tensor: Tensor("network/concat:0", shape=(?, 180, 270, 304), dtype=float32)

 filters: <tf.Variable 'network/slim_decoder/conv2d/weights:0' shape=(3, 3, 304, 1) dtype=float32_ref>
```

Here is the definition of the function:

```
@add_arg_scope

 def depthwise_conv2d(

         inputs, filters, bias=None,

         strides=list([1, 1, 1, 1]), padding='SAME', dilations=list([1, 1, 1, 1]),

         to_batch_norm=False, batch_norm_decay=0.997, is_training=True, activation_fn=None, name=None

 ):

     if isinstance(strides, int):

         strides = list([1, strides, strides, 1])

     if isinstance(dilations, int):

         dilations = list([1, dilations, dilations, 1])

     print("input tensor: " + inputs)

     print("filters: " + filters)

     output = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(

         input=inputs,

         filter=filters,

         strides=strides,

         padding=padding,

         rate=dilations,

         name=name

     )
 
    if bias is not None:

         output = tf.nn.bias_add(output, bias)

     if to_batch_norm:

         output = batch_norm(output, is_training, batch_norm_decay)

     if activation_fn is not None:

         output = activation_fn(output)

     return output
```

I am lost, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your dilatation argument from [1,1,1,1] to [1,1]
tensorflow except list of 2.